# Can someone please help in understanding the statement of this theorem.

Tags: complex-analysis

Can someone please help in understanding the statement of this theorem.

And how does this theorem says that $B(\alpha; \delta ) \subset f(B(a; \epsilon))  $ ?[image]

Thanks

Comment: What is it that you don't understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick $\zeta \in B(\alpha, \delta)$. Then, the above theorem says that the equation $f(z)=\zeta$ has $m$ (simple) roots in $B(a, \epsilon)$.

Let $z$ be such a root. Then $\zeta=f(z) \in f( B(a, \epsilon))$.

Thus, every $\zeta \in B(\alpha, \delta)$ belongs to $f( B(a, \epsilon))$

---

Intuitively, the Theorem says that if $f(z)=\alpha$ has a multiple root at $a$, and if we change $\alpha$ just a bit, the equation will have only simple roots close to the original root.